# overlayfs inside docker container

Tags: docker, overlay, unionfs, overlayfs

Is it possible to mount an overlay fs inside a (privileged) docker container? At least my intuitive approach, which works fine outside of a container, fails:

```
> mkdir /tmp/{up,low,work,merged}
> mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/low/,upperdir=/tmp/up/,workdir=/tmp/work/ /tmp/merged/
mount: /tmp/merged: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Additional information:

- Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
- Kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64
- Debian 10 (host and docker-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found something that worked! Mounting the workdir and upperdir as tmpfs does the trick for me.
Like so:

```
> mkdir /tmp/overlay
> mkdir /tmp/{low,merged}
> mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/overlay
> mkdir /tmp/overlay/{up,work}
> mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/low/,upperdir=/tmp/overlay/up/,workdir=/tmp/overlay/work/ /tmp/merged/
```

I'd still be interested in an explanation why creating an overlay w/o tmpfs fails within a docker container?

Comment: AFAIK it's because overlayfs only supports a single read/write layer (all other layers must be read-only). As the Docker container itself relies on (a read/write layer of) overlayfs, you can't nest another read/write layer.

Answer (score 4):

How to mount an overlayfs inside a docker container:

https://gist.github.com/detunized/7c8fc4c37b49c5475e68ef9574587eee

Basically, you need to run the container with either --privileged or the more secure --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess but I suspect it is because docker is already using overlayfs and overlayfs is refusing to use `upperdir` as another overlayfs.

I suspect this may be due to [whiteout files](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt):

> In order to support rm and rmdir without changing the lower
> filesystem, an overlay filesystem needs to record in the upper
> filesystem that files have been removed.  This is done using whiteouts
> and opaque directories (non-directories are always opaque).
>
> A whiteout is created as a character device with 0/0 device number.
> When a whiteout is found in the upper level of a merged directory, any
> matching name in the lower level is ignored, and the whiteout itself
> is also hidden.

To delete a file that exists in a lowerdir, overlayfs will create a whiteout file and hides *all* whiteout files (device number `0,0`).  This logically means that you cannot create a character device file with number `0,0` inside an overlayfs because that **must** be hidden by overlayfs itself.

If you were allowed to use an overlayfs as an `upperdir` it wouldn't be able to create blackout files and therefore wouldn't be able to `rm` or `rmdir` any files from the lower layers. Because it can't create a character device file with number `0,0` on another overlayfs.